# Change text in button if input has value on the page

Tags: jquery

I would like to do the following and although I would like if in the input at value logout is that at the top of the button tag the word "Login" changes. I have to say I'm not a jquery professional.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row justify-content-between ml-auto">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" id="DropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Login</button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li>
                        <form action="/action" method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                            <legend>Logout</legend>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout">
                            </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

I've found the approach here but do not really get on with it.

```
$ (". Text_div"). Text (function () {
     return $ (this) .text (). replace ("contains", "hello everyone");
});
```

Comment: Please be more clear in what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure what you are asking. But am guessing that you want to change the `DropdownMenu` button's text to "Logout" if your `input` button's text is "Logout".

If so, you can do it like this:

```
var btn_val = $('.nav input[type="submit"]').val();
if( btn_val == 'Logout' )
{
    $('#DropdownMenu').text('Logout');
}
```

[view JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vf96j0md/)